# Social Icons are broken

Tags: html, css

I have a card, with social icons on it, 
and one is under the other.
i've tried inline-block, inline, 
etc all of that stuff.
It still won't fix, though.
Inline-flex works, but then it breaks the card.
Please help.
I'm sorry if the code is messy.
Here is my code.
If you need more code or whatever, here is the [Website](https://www.discordnoir.xyz/credits.html) it is on.

Thank you.

```css
.nyrisoc {
    position:relative;
    letter-spacing: 20px;
    top:270px;
    left:96px;
    margin:0px;
   
  }
  .cardtitle {
    position: relative;
    left: 55px;
    top: 12px;
    text-decoration: underline solid transparent;
    transition: text-decoration 1s ease;
    margin-right: 0 0 0;
    width: 245px;
  }
  
  .center2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  .cardtitle:hover {
    text-decoration: underline solid Currentcolor;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .center {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  #cardlink {
    text-decoration: underline solid transparent;
    transition: text-decoration 1s ease;
    cursor:pointer;
  }
  .carddis {
    position: relative;
    top: -68px;
    right: 60px;
    color: gray;
    font-size: 17px;
  }
  .stuffyes {
    position: relative;
    bottom:194px;
  }
  .cardinfo {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 70px;
    left: 70px;
  }
  .allcrds {
    display:inline-table;
    position:relative;
    bottom:-30px;
    right:160px;
  }
  .card {
    width:269px;
    background-color: rgb(44, 44, 44);
    height:330px;
    border-radius:30px;
    font-family:roboto;
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0.75rem black);
    position:relative;
    left:20px;
    bottom:90px;
    margin: 27px;
  }
  .cname {
    color:white;
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0.75rem black);
    opacity:100%;
    font-family:roboto;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    top:180px;
  }
  .fab {
    color:white;
    cursor:pointer;
    transition: color 1s ease;
  }
  .fab:hover {
    color:gray;
  }
  #cardlink:hover {
    text-decoration: underline solid currentColor;
  }
  .socials {
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    top:230px;
    display:inline-flex;
    letter-spacing: 20px;
    left:72px;
    top:270px;
  }
  .desctx {
    color:rgb(196, 192, 192);
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0.75rem black);
    text-align:center;
    font-family:roboto;
    position:relative;
    top:305px;
  }
  .pfpy {
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0.75rem black);
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
    border-radius:50px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Credits | Discord Noir</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/css/cred.css">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3bc98b09b4.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        </head>
        <body>

    <div class="allcrds">
        <!-- Nyria Card -->
        <div class="card" onContextMenu="return false;">
            <div class="nyrisoc" onContextMenu="return false;">
              <div class="discord" onContextMenu="return false;">
                <i class="fab fa-2x fa-discord" onContextMenu="return false;" onclick='window.open("https://discord.com/users/265924886461939712/");return false;'></i>
              </div>
              <div class="github" onContextMenu="return false;">
                <i class="fab fa-2x fa-github" onContextMenu="return false;" onclick='window.open("https://www.github.com/NYRI4");return false;'></i>
              </div>
              
            </div>
            <div class="stuffyes">
            <h2 class="desctx" onContextMenu="return false;"><br /><span onclick='window.open("https://github.com/NYRI4/Discolored");return false;' id="cardlink">Discolored</span></h2>
        <h1 class="cname" onContextMenu="return false;">Nyria</h1>
        <img class="pfpy center2"
          src="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/65369563?v=4"
          draggable="false"
          alt=" Spyglass Logo"
          onContextMenu="return false;"
          />
        </div>
          </div>
        </div>



         <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script href="src/js/main.js">
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This use case (using `display: inline-table`) isn't ideal when flexbox is available. You can accomplish everything you need very quickly with flexbox, please [read this for more information](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). You can look up more articles on flexbox (or CSS grid), this should solve your positioning problems.

Comment: This website isn't going to work as-is. The whole body has an overflow-y hidden, that means on mobile or smaller screens, you won't even be able to see your card because you won't be able to scroll. I can tell y'all don't have alot of front -end experience. If things are relatively positioned, then there shouldn't be any left, top, bottom, right styles uses. Those are for positioning absolute elements. I'll help ya out, I remember when I was at this stage.

Comment: @AjayPillay im very confused, it didnt work. I might be using it wrong, idk flexbox confuses me. :(

Comment: @Sensoray I know it's not mobile-friendly. That wasnt the question tho. I'm gonna make it mobile friendly soon, dont worry mate.

Comment: @HereticMonkey THANK YOU. exactly. i've literally seen a lot of professional websites do that, and even seen it on code teaching websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
.nyrisoc > * {
  width: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 65px;
}
```

Comment: Answers which provide an explanation of how code solves the problem are more often upvoted than those which simply say “try this” and a bunch of code. The goal of Stack Overflow is to help not just the OP, but everyone who has the same question for years afterwards.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Oh, sorry sir.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thank you very much for pointing out that my quick solution came without explanations or links to the CSS documentation. Here's the link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS , you are more than welcome to edit my post with a proper explanation. Thank you in advance!
OP didn't ask for an explanation, OP asked for a solution.

Comment: And,, as I said, the goal of Stack Overflow is to help not just the OP, but everyone who has the same question for years afterwards. If you prefer to ignore the stated purpose of the site you are contributing to, I can't stop you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to your background, so it won't look quite right, but this should be good enough to send y'all in the right direction.

Items that are positioned relatively don't need to be manually set using top,bottom,left or right. Also the heirarchy of your elements should follow what you want to be seen on the screen. So if the image is at the top of the card, the element containing the image should be at the top of the card, not the bottom. I fixed some other stuff that should help it be a bit more responsive and user-friendly, a bit too much to list, but if you have any questions, let me know and I'm happy to help / answer.

```css
.nyrisoc {
    position:relative;
    letter-spacing: 20px;
    /* top:270px; */
    /* left:96px; */
    margin:0px;
  }
  .cardtitle {
    position: relative;
    left: 55px;
    top: 12px;
    text-decoration: underline solid transparent;
    transition: text-decoration 1s ease;
    margin-right: 0 0 0;
    width: 245px;
  }
  
  .center2 {
    position: absolute;
    /* top: 70px; */
    /* left: 50%; */
    /* transform: translate(-50%, -50%); */
  }
  .cardtitle:hover {
    text-decoration: underline solid Currentcolor;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .center {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  #cardlink {
    text-decoration: underline solid transparent;
    transition: text-decoration 1s ease;
    cursor:pointer;
  }
  .carddis {
    position: relative;
    top: -68px;
    right: 60px;
    color: gray;
    font-size: 17px;
  }
  .stuffyes {
    position: relative;
    /* bottom:194px; */
  }
  .cardinfo {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 70px;
    left: 70px;
  }
  .allcrds {
    /* display:inline-table; */
    position:relative;
    /* bottom:-30px; */
    /* right:160px; */
  }
  .card {
    width:269px;
    background-color: rgb(44, 44, 44);
    height:330px;
    border-radius:30px;
    font-family:roboto;
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0.75rem black);
    position:relative;
    /* left:20px; */
    /* bottom:90px; */
    /* margin: 27px; */
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 15px 30px;
    padding: 15px 0 30px;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  .cname {
    color:white;
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0.75rem black);
    opacity:100%;
    font-family:roboto;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    /* top:180px; */
  }
  .fab {
    color:white;
    cursor:pointer;
    transition: color 1s ease;
  }
  .fab:hover {
    color:gray;
  }
  #cardlink:hover {
    text-decoration: underline solid currentColor;
  }
  .socials {
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    /* top:230px; */
    display: block;
    /* letter-spacing: 20px; */
    /* left:72px; */
    /* top:270px; */
  }
  .desctx {
    color:rgb(196, 192, 192);
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0.75rem black);
    text-align:center;
    font-family:roboto;
    position:relative;
    /* top:305px; */
    height: 70px;
  }
  .pfpy {
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0.75rem black);
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
    border-radius:50px;
    margin: 30px auto 0;
    display: block;
  }
  .socials div{
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0 5px;
  }
```

```html
<head><script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3bc98b09b4.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script></head>
<body>
        <div class="navbar2">

            <div class="navbarbg">
            </div>
                <ul class="nvbritms">
                    <li class="hm" onclick="location.href = '/index.html';">Home</li>
                    <li class="credss" onclick="location.href = '/credits.html';">Credits</li>
                    <li class="discordinv" onclick="window.open(&quot;https://www.discord.gg/knHgcbw9vs&quot;);return false;">Discord</li>

                    
                </ul>
                
         </div>         
         <img class="logo22" src="/src/img/DNLogoW.png" onclick="location.href = '/index.html';">
         

         <!-- Cards -->
         <div class="allcrds">
         <!-- Snapperito Card -->
         <div class="card" oncontextmenu="return false;">
            <div class="stuffyes">
            <img class="pfpy center2" src="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/52221287?v=4" draggable="false" alt=" Spyglass Logo" oncontextmenu="return false;"><h2 class="desctx" oncontextmenu="return false;"><span onclick="window.open(&quot;https://github.com/Snippets-For-Discord/theme-warnings&quot;);return false;" id="cardlink">Theme Warnings</span><br><span onclick="window.open(&quot;https://github.com/snappercord/Settings-Icons&quot;);return false;" id="cardlink">Settings Icons</span></h2>
        <h1 class="cname" oncontextmenu="return false;">Snapperito</h1>
        
        </div><div class="socials" oncontextmenu="return false;">
              <div class="discord" oncontextmenu="return false;" style="
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px;
">
                <i class="fab fa-2x fa-discord" oncontextmenu="return false;" onclick="window.open(&quot;https://discord.com/users/431883840483491850/&quot;);return false;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="github" oncontextmenu="return false;" style="
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px;
">
                <i class="fab fa-2x fa-github" oncontextmenu="return false;" onclick="window.open(&quot;https://www.github.com/snapperito&quot;);return false;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="instagram" oncontextmenu="return false;" onclick="window.open(&quot;https://www.instagram.com/snapperito/&quot;);return false;" style="
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px;
">
                <i class="fab fa-2x fa-instagram" oncontextmenu="return false;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>
              
            </div>
            
          </div><div class="card" oncontextmenu="return false;">
            <div class="stuffyes">
            <img class="pfpy center2" src="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/65369563?v=4" draggable="false" alt=" Spyglass Logo" oncontextmenu="return false;"><h2 class="desctx" oncontextmenu="return false;"><span onclick="window.open(&quot;https://github.com/NYRI4/Discolored&quot;);return false;" id="cardlink">Discolored</span></h2>
        <h1 class="cname" oncontextmenu="return false;">Nyria</h1>
        
        </div><div class="socials" oncontextmenu="return false;">
              <div class="discord" oncontextmenu="return false;" style="
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px;
">
                <i class="fab fa-2x fa-discord" oncontextmenu="return false;" onclick="window.open(&quot;https://discord.com/users/265924886461939712/&quot;);return false;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="github" oncontextmenu="return false;" style="
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px;
">
                <i class="fab fa-2x fa-github" oncontextmenu="return false;" onclick="window.open(&quot;https://www.github.com/NYRI4&quot;);return false;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>
              
            </div>
            
          </div>
        </div>
    
    <div class="allcrds">
        <!-- Nyria Card -->
        
        </div>



         <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script href="src/js/main.js">
        </script>
    
</body>
```

Comment: `.cardtitle { position: relative; left: 55px; top: 12px; …` hmm…